# Why this compilation error in this?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
static int MOD = 1000000007;
public class power {
    public static long power(long num, int p) {
        if (p == 0) return 1;
        if (p == 1) return num;
        long number = num;
        for (int i = 2; i <= p; i++) {
            num *= number;
            num %= MOD;
        }
        return num;
    }
};
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int N, M;
        long[] T = new long[1001];
        long[] S = new long[1001];
        long[] P = new long[1001];
        T[0] = T[1] = 1;
        T[2] = 2;
        T[3] = 4;
        T[4] = 8;
        P[0] = P[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 5; i <= 1000; i++)
        T[i] = (T[i - 1] + T[i - 2] + T[i - 3] + T[i - 4]) % MOD;
        S[0] = 1;
        S[1] = 1;
        long sum;
        int Tt;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Tt = Integer.parseInt(line);
        for (int t = 0; t < Tt; t++) {
            line = br.readLine();
            String[] inputStr = line.split(" ");
            N = Integer.parseInt(inputStr[0]);
            M = Integer.parseInt(inputStr[1]);
            power p = new power();
            for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
            P[i] = p.power(T[i], N);
            for (int i = 2; i <= M; i++) {
                sum = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                    sum += (S[j] * P[i - j]) % MOD;
                    sum %= MOD1;
                }
                S[i] = (P[i] - sum);
                S[i] = S[i] % MOD;
            }
            while (S[M] < 0)
            S[M] += MOD;
            System.out.println(S[M]);
        }
    }
}
```

On compilation, it gives an error that,

```
class,interface, or enum expected
static int MOD = 100000007;
```

Why is it so? Also, is their any other error that can lead to compilation error? How can I correct it? I am new to Java. I don't understand why is their a error in the first place.

Comment: You to make the declaration with the bounds of class, interface or enum context

Comment: How do I do it then? I want it to be accessed by main as well as power.

Comment: It's a static final value, it'll be available to every body, but it needs to be defined within a class/interface/enum context

Answer (score 1):

```
static int MOD = 1000000007;
```

written out side class.

Include it inside `class power` then use `power.MOD`

Code should be :

```
public class power {
       static int MOD = 1000000007;
       //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the field must be inside of the class:

Change to :

```
public class power {
   static int MOD = 1000000007;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it this way

```
public class power {
    public static int MOD = 1000000007;
```

And you can access it through class name in your main method.

```
power.MOD
```

**Note:**
You should not have method name as your class name (in your case `power`).

---

I have removed all compilation error. Added comments for the changes which I have done.

```
public class Power {

    public static int MOD = 1000000007;

    public static long findPower(long num, int p) { // changed method name as it was same as class name

        if (p == 0)
            return 1;
        if (p == 1)
            return num;

        long number = num;
        for (int i = 2; i <= p; i++) {
            num *= number;
            num %= MOD;
        }
        return num;
    }
}

class Solution { // removed public. If you want to use public then you will have to create another java file name Solution.java and paste Solution class code inside that java file.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int N, M;

        long[] T = new long[1001];
        long[] S = new long[1001];
        long[] P = new long[1001];

        T[0] = T[1] = 1;
        T[2] = 2;
        T[3] = 4;
        T[4] = 8;

        P[0] = P[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 5; i <= 1000; i++)
            T[i] = (T[i - 1] + T[i - 2] + T[i - 3] + T[i - 4]) % Power.MOD; // access using Power.MOD

        S[0] = 1;
        S[1] = 1;

        long sum;
        int Tt;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        Tt = Integer.parseInt(line);

        for (int t = 0; t < Tt; t++) {
            line = br.readLine();
            String[] inputStr = line.split(" ");
            N = Integer.parseInt(inputStr[0]);
            M = Integer.parseInt(inputStr[1]);
            // Power p = new Power(); 
            for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
                P[i] = Power.findPower(T[i], N); // No need to use object, you can directly access static methods using class

            for (int i = 2; i <= M; i++) {
                sum = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                    sum += (S[j] * P[i - j]) % Power.MOD;
                    sum %= Power.MOD;
                }
                S[i] = (P[i] - sum);
                S[i] = S[i] % Power.MOD;
            }
            while (S[M] < 0)
                S[M] += Power.MOD;
            System.out.println(S[M]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I access it from main and the power function itself then?

Comment: It gives the compilation error now as, `
class Solution is public and should be declared in a file named Solution.Java`

Comment: Remove public from class Solution.

Comment: Is this code is present in single Java file?  there should be only one public class per java file.

Comment: @JohnLui, updated my answer with compilable code. Note: I have not executed your code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare static int MOD = 1000000007; inside the power class and import package to access from main method.

```
 import static com.regex.power.MOD;
 public class power  {
 static int MOD = 1000000007;
```